# Corda - RedeemFungibleTokens giving "Insufficient spendable states" even using the same query that finds tokens via QuerybyAccount

Tags: corda

The following flow:

SignedTransaction stx =subFlow(new RedeemFungibleTokens(amt, issuer, new LinkedList(), criteria));

...is giving me "InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient spendable states identified for 1 TokenType(tokenIdentifier='ABC', fractionDigits=0) issued by Node1."

This even though I am using identical "criteria" to a call to QuerybyAccount which returns a state with 30 of these tokens.  And actually, even if I take out the "criteria" entirely, it still gives the same exception.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The trick was mentioned here:
https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/issues/146

Simply to use TokenType rather than IssuedTokenType.  who knew?  :)